# How can I Insert data Into a table? I need to add a new record with the existing data

Tags: sql

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj4Cd.png)

How can I write a SQL query for this scenario?

In the above table for the existing records I need to insert a new amount
as $100

EX:

```
  A007       | Ramasundar           | Bangalore          |       100 | 
....
  003        | Alex                 | London             |       100 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you inserting it into the COMMISSION column?

```
INSERT INTO table_name (COMMISSION) VALUES (100);
```